# Send files from one remote server using JSch to another server using JSch too

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I would like to send files from my first remote server to another one:

```
public boolean uploadFile() throws JSchException, SftpException {
    ChannelSftp channelSftpA = createChannelSftp();
    ChannelSftp channelSftpB = createChannelSftp();
    channelSftpA.connect();
    channelSftpB.connect();

    localFilePath = "/data/upload/readme.txt";
    remoteFilePath = "/bingo/pdf/";

    channelSftpA.cd(localFilePath);
    channelSftpA.put(localFilePath + "readme.txt", remoteFilePath + "readme.txt");
```

But it doesn't work. Should I put `channelB.put` into my first `channelA.put`?

Comment: See also [Send files directly from remote A to remote B from local using JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74397232/850848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correct, you code will be run from third server, for transferring file you should get file from `server A`, and that put on `server B`. By the way users under which you are going to download and upload files should have access to specified folders!

```
private boolean transferFile() throws JSchException, SftpException {
    ChannelSftp channelSftpA = createChannelSftp();
    ChannelSftp channelSftpB = createChannelSftp();
    channelSftpA.connect();
    channelSftpB.connect();

    String fileName = "readme.txt";
    String remoteFilePathFrom = "/folderFrom/";
    String remoteFilePathTo = "/folderTo/";

    InputStream srcInputStream = channelSftpA.get(remoteFilePathFrom + fileName);
    channelSftpB.put(srcInputStream, remoteFilePathTo + fileName);
    System.out.println("Transfer has been completed");

    channelSftpA.exit();
    channelSftpB.exit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help!