# Send files directly from remote A to remote B from local using JSch?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I have read [Send files from one remote server using JSch to another server using JSch too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657619/send-files-from-one-remote-server-using-jsch-to-another-server-using-jsch-too) and the code seems very promising.
But one downside it has is it uses local machine as buffer for transferring files.
(So file flows like Remote A – Local – Remote B)

I want send any protocol (SSH maybe) to remote A and remote A send files to remote B directly (using SFTP).
(desirable: Remote A – Remote B)

It doesn't have to use JSch specifically, but it is the only one seems workable I have found so far.

It can be done manually but all jobs must be done automatically.

Any single keyword or pseudo-code would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no common API (maybe except for FTP FXP) for transferring files directly between two remote machines.

All you can do is to [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2405885/850848) whatever commands you have available on one server that transfers files to/from the other. You didn't tell us anything about your servers. But most Linux/Windows servers would have some `sftp`/`scp` client available.

---

*And btw OpenSSH `scp` has transfer between two remote machine built in. So you can execute it on the local machine. See [How to transfer a file between two remote servers using scp from a third, local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28831329/850848) But that's not really much help, as it basically does ssh to one server and executes `scp` there to transfer files to/from the order server. So it does what I've suggested you to do with JSch above.*

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation there are no APIs on SFTP about transferring between remotes. I will try SCP!